# Trying to use EJS with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to setup my first app using EJS (Normally use Jade) and I've got it all setup and my pages are loading, I followed a tutorial on how to do it, this is my layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title> 
            <%= title %>
        </title>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
         <!--[if lt IE 9]>
             <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
         <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>
        <%- body %>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my Home page

```
<div class='title'>
    <%= title %>
</div>
```

But when I load the home page, and view page source, all I see is the Home page elements, I don't see `html, body, head, title` any of that stuff. Not sure why, this is my app.js

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and my 2 files are `layout.ejs, index.ejs`

Thanks in advance!

Following: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/31/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of Express (3.x) don't support layouts anymore (see this [migration page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#view-system-changes)).

Instead (also suggested by the migration page), you can use [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) to get back that functionality. The GitHub page of `ejs-locals` gives some easy examples how to get layouts working with Express 3.

Answer (score -1):

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

add this to app.js